# ResolveUrl not working inline

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the error on the below code in asp.net 4.0

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%#=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>'></script>
```

Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '='

I am using this code in Site.Master in head tag

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't use `<%#` and `<%=` at the same time. Try it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>'></script>
```

**EDIT**
If you are getting an error that states:

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

when you try to use `<%= ResolveUrl(...`, it is because something in your code is attempting to add controls to your header control in Site.Master. If that is the case, switch the script tag to read:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>'></script>
```

and make sure you call the `DataBind()` method on the header tag at some point (for example, from the Page_Load method for Site.Master):

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Header.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)  Also, if you need to use # then its just <%#Resolve,  but you need to ensure that Page.DataBind(); is called somewhere.

Comment: Hi got this error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResolveUrl` with `Eval` like this. No external code needed.

```xml
<img src='<%# ResolveUrl(Eval("FILE_URL").ToString()) %>' alt=""
     style="width:50px;height:50px"/>
```